# Android Change(switch) between activities in Asynctask with ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have two activities : LoginActivity and MainActivity

I used AsyncTask in LoginActivity like below :

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result.contains("success")) { //login success

                Intent intent_name = new Intent();
                intent_name.setClass(LoginActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent_name);

            } else {

            }

        }
```

(I changed LoginActivity.this to getApplicationContext() and mContext which received context via constructor)

and in the MainActivity

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
```

when I laucnh the app and get "success" from the server,

`"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo"` is triggered with `MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)`

MainActivity.java:24 is where the `ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();` is located.

is there any suspected mistake? Thank you!

- P.S. I want to contain the login cookie(session) for sharing with MainActivity, webView in MainActivity. How can I do that?

---

Logcat below

```
30904-30904/com.sintranet.inf.mini E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sintranet.inf.mini/com.sintranet.inf.mini.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2098)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4886)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sintranet.inf.mini.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5240)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2037)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2098)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4886)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post the full stacktrace.

Comment: @Raghunandan added logcat

Comment: what is MainActivity.java line 24??

Comment: @Raghunandan the line was changed.. :24 is actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

Comment: `actionbar` is null fix it

Comment: @Raghunandan in addition, without LoginActivity (before making LoginAcitivity), the MainActivity worked properly.

Comment: your stacktrace tells there is a NPE @ line 24. so actionbar is null

Comment: @Raghunandan actionbar is null is obvious. getActionBar() doesn't return any reference which was previously returning correct one that MainActivity worked fine. I didn't edit MainActivity after coding for the LoginActivity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49816/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-klados)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actionbar could be null possibly due to application theme.

Please check your application theme from android manifest from application/activity tag and also check window theme is not changed from java code.